What was the last capture in this game of monochromatic chess?
Here is a new retrograde analysis puzzle - but this one is not about an ordinary game of chess! Instead, Black and White set out to play a game of monochromatic chess. In this variant, the pieces may only move between squares of the same checkerboard colour (while also adhering to the usual movement rules). For instance, this means that a knight cannot move at all, and that every pawn move must either be a double step or a capture (and many more little things).
This rule also applies to checks (and mate) - a king can only be checked by pieces of the same square colour as itself. In particular, it is no problem to have the two kings placed on adjacent squares.
The page linked above (from the retrograde analysis corner) also has an example puzzle for this condition which may help you to get familiar with this variant. With all that said:
Can you determine the last capture of this game?


(8+9) FEN: k4K2/pr1p1pp1/p7/2p1p3/1PP5/6P1/P1PP4/6N1

And, if you found the answer to that, you will also have no trouble answering the little
Bonus Question:

 Can you determine the first 13 single moves of this game?

Please provide your reasoning in your answer. Have fun solving this! :)

Maybe it's time for a small pointer on where to start looking:
Hint 1:

 What does the general position of the white King tell you about the pawns on c5 and e5? Try to determine their exact history.


This is such a beautiful puzzle. I'm at the point where two lines of reasoning intersect, and can't wait to find out what will play out.

Solution
I chose not to use spoiler blocks, partly because it is too troublesome, partly because the text is so long that you couldn't accidentally spoil yourself.
Preliminaries
There are useful facts that one can derive from the rules of monochromatic chess:

Pawns can only move two squares or capture
Rooks have "parity": a rook can only access half of the squares of the same colour that it started on (so only a quarter of the entire board)
Only kingside castling is possible
Knights cannot move

Notation
A piece is denoted by (Colour)(Piece type at the start of the game)(Starting file if necessary). For example, the white rook starting at a1 is WRa, and the black pawn starting at h7 is Bh.
Preliminary captures map (to be refined later)
Using these very restrictive rules and considering which pieces are alive, taking into account their starting square colour, we can arrive at the following captures.
Black capturing white:

b7 x a6 (WBf or WQ)
h7 x (WQ or WBf), WRh, Wg, [one of Wh/Wf] e.p., eventually promoting to rook
WRa, WBc are described later
promoted rook x WNb

White capturing black:

e2 x d3 BBc x d4 BRa
[one of f2/h2] x g3 [one of BQ/BBf]
unknown fate: the other [one of BQ/BBf], BNb, BNg, BRh

Chains of reasoning

WRa getting out

requires WBc getting out

requires Wb moving


also requires WNb taken by the promoted BR


c4 x BRa

requires BK having gone into the top left via e6

requires BK castling kingside

requires BNg dying to WQ or WBf







The Black e pawn does not capture anything
We know that WK must enter d6 after the check of either b6 or f6. But if it is f6 then it reveals the unmoved and alive  (it needs to die on g3) BBf that controls d6. So this is impossible.
This also means that Nb8 must be captured by WK.
Table of fates
Notation: D = died (possibly followed by the square it died on), T = to (the starting square of the piece it died to), A = alive (followed by its current square if it has moved)
Y = one of them DTh7 e.p., the other one A(g3)
Note: technically there is no reason that Wb has to capture BQ and BRh. They can also be captured by WBc if we decide to just push b4.




a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h




8
Ra8
Nb8
Bc8
Qd8
Ke8
Bf8
Ng8
Rh8



Dc4Te2
Db8Te1
Dd3Te2
DTb2
A(a8)
Dg3
Dg8Td1
Db4Tb2


7
a7
b7
c7
d7
e7
f7
g7
h7



A
A(a6)
A(c5)
A
A(e5)
A
A
A(b7)


2
a2
b2
c2
d2
e2
f2
g2
h2



A
A(b4)
A
A
A(c4)
Y
Dg4Th7
Y


1
a1
b1
c1
d1
e1
f1
g1
h1



Dc5Tc7
Db1Th7
Db6Tc7
Da6Tb7
A
DTh7
A
DTh7



Initial history

The initial history of 1. g4 h5 2. Bg2 hxg4 3. f4 gxf3 4. Kf2 fxg2 5. Ke3 gxh1=R 6. Kd4 e5+ 7. Kc3 is absolutely forced since the White King needs to get to the left side before e5 is played.

Refined fates
Black capturing white:

b7 x a6 WQ
h7 x WBf, WRh, Wg, Wf e.p.
c7 x WBc b6 x WRa c5
promoted rook x WNb

White capturing black:

e2 x d3 BBc x d4 BRa
h2 x g3 BBf
b2 x (a3 or c3) BQ x b4 BRh (or these are taken by WBc)
BNb DT WK
BNg DT Qd1

Final Proof game
Lichess study: https://lichess.org/study/dD0n4css/VziQKFjw

g4 h5 2. Bg2 hxg4 3. f4 gxf3 4. Kf2 fxg2 5. Ke3 gxh1=R 6. Kd4 e5+ 7. Kc3 Qf6 8. Qf1 Qd8 9. Qh3 Qf6 10. Qh7 Qd8 11. Qxg8 Qf6 12. Qh7 Qd6 13. Qd3 Be7 14. Qa6 O-O 15. Qd3 Qa3+ 16. bxa3 Bh4 17. Kb4 Bg3 18. hxg3 Rh5 19. Qa6 bxa6 20. Bb2 Bb7 21. Bd4 Be4 22. Bb6 Rf5 23. Kc5 cxb6+ 24. Kd6 Rf1 25. Ke7 Rxb1 26. Kd6 Rb5 27. Re1 Bd3 28. exd3 Kh7 29. Re3 Kg6 30. Re1 Rh8 31. Re3 Rh4 32. Re1 Rhb4 33. axb4 Kf5 34. Kc7 Kg6

rn6/p1Kp1pp1/pp4k1/1r2p3/1P6/3P2P1/P1PP4/4R1N1 w - - 3 35
Increment 35 to 36, paste it into Lichess board editor, then manually make the illegal move in normal chess

Kxb8 Kf5

to get the FEN
rK6/p2p1pp1/pp6/1r2pk2/1P6/3P2P1/P1PP4/4R1N1 w - - 3 36
and we continue with

Kc7 Re8 37. Kd6 Re6+ 38. Kc7 Rg6 39. Kd8 Ke6 40. Kc7 Kd5 41. Kd8 Kc6 42. Ke7 Kb7 43. Kd8 Ka8 44. Re3 Rg4 45. Ke7 Rc4 46. dxc4 Kb7 47. Rc3 Rd5 48. Ra3 Ka8 49. Ra5 Kb7 50. Rc5 Ka8 51. Rc7 Rb5 52. Rc5 bxc5 53. Kf8 Rb7

k4K2/pr1p1pp1/p7/2p1p3/1PP5/6P1/P1PP4/6N1 w - - 2 54
Thanks Retudin for the trick of temporarily storing the WR on c7. When doing the proof game since the tempo is wrong, I wasted a move on White's move 47.
Final answer (the last capture)
Pawn b6 takes c5 Rook (which was from a1)

+1 for "I chose not to use spoiler blocks". I didn't even (yet) read your response, but spoilers are WAY overused on PSE.

Looks pretty good to me! Now you only need to argue why that last capture in your PG had to come last, and find out how to get the black rook "inside" at the end, but that last part should be straightforward :)

The last capture is

 bxc5

The opening restrictions:

 1/ Ra7 must be the promoted h-pawn
 2/ The black king must castle; freezing Rh8 until that is done
 3/ Bf8 cannot be captured before e7 opens, thus the white king cannot enter e6 with exf6,Kd6 due to check.
 4/ The white king must move (thus) though d4, and cxb6 and e7e5 cannot be played before it gets there
 Thus black can only move its h-pawn until the white King is on d4 or black can capture with a pawn.

 5/ Blacks h-pawn captures 4 times and the b pawn 1 time, so there are less than 4 captures for the c and e pawn.
 6/ Whites king must move through d6 and can only move there directly after the capture cxb6 (after exf6 is prohibited due to 4/)
 Thus black cannot use its c or e pawn before the white king is on d4.

 The capture fxg3 or hxg3 can only be made after black has put a piece there,
 This is only possible after c7 or e7 is open.
 Thus the king must be on d4 before that capture, and thus the f pawn must capture en-passant on f3.

 The f-pawn cannot capture the queen and bishop since Rh1 cannot be captured at a6.
 A promoted rook on h1 will be stuck until h2 is open.
 Thus black can do at most 5 moves before something other than the f-pawn must move

The opening moves:

 Black needs 3 moves to enable its captures.
 Thus white has 3 moves to capture a6 or reach d4. Moving to a6 costs more than 3 moves.

 Thus the starting sequence is:
 g4,h5 Bg2,hxg4 f4,gxf3 Kf2,fxg2 Ke3,gxh1 Kd4 (followed by e5 Kc3)
  And all blacks capture locations are clear: g4 f2(en-passant) g2 h1 a6 b6 c5 b1.

The end game restrictions:

  The rook from a1 can only be captured at c5 and to allow that:
 a/ b2 must be played to unblock the bishop.
 b/ hxg3 must be played to unblock the promoted rook, which is the only piece that can capture at b2.
 c/ exd3 must be played.
 With e5,g3 and g1 on their final position, the rook must go through e1-e3-c3.
 Thus dxc4 must be played, and the only route to c5 is a1-e1-e3-a3-a5-c5 which means the b-pawn is already on b3.

 To get whites e-pawn on c3, whites a8-rook must get there (and whites c8-bishop needs to get to d3).
 To capture Kb8 only the king and the bishop are available; but the bishop is needed to open c7.
 Thus the king takes b8 before rook a1 can get past d3  - note that this is allowed in monochromatic chess!

The mid game restrictions:

 This leaves only only 2 black-fielded black pieces unaccounted for.
 If white plays b2b4 there is no way the bishop from c1 can pass the king to be sacrificed at b2 while the king is at c3.
 Thus the b-pawn gets at its destination with 2 captures, which both occur before Ra1 can reach line5.

Conclusion

 Ra1 can only be moved to c5 to be captured from b6 after all other captures have been made.

Example game (up to illegal move in normal chess):

 1. g4 h5 2. Bg2 hxg4 3. f3 gxf3 4. Kf2 fxg2 5. Ke3 gxh1=R 6. Kd4 e5+ 7. Kc3 Qh4 8. Qf1 Qg3+ 9. hxg3 R1h5 10. Qh3 Rf5 11. Qh7 Rf1 12. Qxg8 Rf5 13. Qh7 Ba3 14. Qg6 O-O 15. Qa6 bxa6 16. bxa3 Rf3+ 17. Kb4 Rb3+ 18. Kc5 Rxb1 19. Bb2 Kh7 20. Bc3 Kg6 21. Ba5 Kf5 22. Bb6 cxb6+ 23. Kd6 Rb5 24. Kc7 Rd5 (24... Bb7 25. Re1 Be4 26. Ra1 Rh8 27. Re1 Bd3 28. exd3 Rh4 29. Re3 Rhb4 30. axb4 Rd5)
 now  Kc7 can take knight and move away,
 then Ra8 can move to/sacrifice on c4
 then Re3 can move to c7
 then Rd5b5 Rc7c5 bxc5 (and the rest is trivial)


It's a nice idea to use c7. Here's a complete proof game using your idea, for completeness. Before illegal move the FEN is
rn6/p1Kp1pp1/pp6/3rpk2/1P6/3PR1P1/P1PP4/6N1 w - - 1 31
Increment 31 to 32, paste it into Lichess board editor, then manually make 31. Kxb8 Rb5 , and export the FEN to get
rK6/p2p1pp1/pp6/1r2pk2/1P6/3PR1P1/P1PP4/6N1 w - - 1 32, import and play

Kc7 Re8 33. Kd6 Re6+ 34. Kc7 Rg6 35. Kd8 Rg4 36. Kc7 Ke6 37. Kd8 Kd5 38. Ke7 Kc6 39. Kd8 Kb7 40. Ke7 Ka8 41. Kd8 Rc4 42. dxc4 Rd5 43. Ra3 Rb5 44. Ra5 Rd5 45. Rc5 Kb7 46. Rc7+ Ka8 47. Ke7 Rb5 48. Rc5 bxc5 49. Kf8 Rb7


This is a very good answer, thanks for taking the time! :)

This answer is in progress.

 ralphmerridew observed that the black rook is promoted, because the rook from a8 cannot reach b7.


 The rook was promoted from the pawn h7.


 The white pawn at c4 captured two black pieces, one at c4 and the other at d3.


 The only possibility for this is when the captured pieces are the black bishop and the black rook.


 Since the pawn from h7 was promoted.


 It captured at least four white pieces.


 But then there remains no white piece to be captured at a6 by the pawn b7, a contradiction.


 Thus the position is illegal.


 Oops...


 But, wait!


 A pawn can do some little things.


 It captured a white pawn either from f2 or from h2 en passant.


 Now ask how white king reached f8?


 Anyway it has to be at d6 before.


 In order to white king not to be in check when it entered d6 for the first time, no pawn from c7 and e7 were at their places. So it happened via either ... c7xb6+ Kc5-d6 or ... e7xf6+ Ke5-d6.


 Anyway, one (and only one) of pawns from c7 and e7 captured the white rook and bishop.


 The white knight was captured by the promoted black rook.


 The black king left e8 via the short castle.


 And the black knight at g8 was captured before that


 by the white queen or the white bishop


 (the pawn from g2 could not reach the eighth vertical, because it captured at most three black pieces)


A simplification to part of this is to notice that the black rook must be promoted.  (An original black rook can't reach that square in monochromatic.)

@ralphmerridew Thanks, I did not think about this. This observation not only simplifies my analysis, but changes it. I updated the answer.
